# I have one bad grade on my transcript and I'm thinking of applying for MS CS programs at top US Graduate schools. How badly would my chances be hurt?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science, international-students

I am currently studying Computer Science and Engineering at a top Indian engineering school (IIT). However, I have a CD (5 out of 10) grade in one subject (System Software Laboratory) in one semester. My overall grade is pretty good but I have a bad grade for this one subject. For context, this grade is kind of equivalent to a D in the US.

Answer (score -1):

There's no question it will hurt.  You already know that.  How much it hurts depends on where you're applying and whether it's to a master's or PhD program.

Top PhD programs could fill every spot with students who only have 4.0 (perfect) averages.  The reason they accept students with less than perfect averages is because they also consider your LORs (letters of recommendation) and your essays, especially, your SOP (statement of purpose), which may be enough to overcome that one bad grade.  Lesser programs accept less.

If you're applying to a master's program, admissions are generally more accommodating since they don't have to assign a faculty advisor and they know most master's students are heading into industry, not academia.

Comment: I doubt, however, that it will hurt much, and it won't be the major determinant. Especially if it is an outlier.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative answer! I am going to apply to Masters programs and not the Ph.D. programs.

Comment: For a master's, good chance it won't hurt you very much.  But do your best to get some strong LORs.  Good luck.